# Cleaning GIT_DIR objects/incoming-* temporary directories

Tags: git

Do I need to do anything to clean up stale-looking directories with names like `objects/incoming-a16812` in a bare Git repository? There's a cron job that runs `git gc` monthly that's working just fine, but these directories are accumulating across my repositories.

I have some bare repositories that are accessed over SSH. When looking at a storage report for the server that hosts these repositories, I saw that there were a number of old, temporary looking directories and files under `objects` with names like `incoming-a16812` with what appear to be temporary packfiles:

```
# the stat format string is: name type creation-time modification-time
user@host[.../repos/some-repo.git/objects]% find . -exec stat -f $'%N\t%ST\t%Sc\t%Sm' {} ';'
.       /       Mar 18 00:27:51 2020    Mar 18 00:27:51 2020
./incoming-a16812       /       Jul 26 11:29:02 2019    Jul 26 11:29:02 2019
./incoming-a16812/pack  /       Jul 26 11:29:13 2019    Jul 26 11:29:13 2019
./incoming-a16812/pack/tmp_pack_6CUMWa  *       Jul 26 11:30:16 2019    Jul 26 11:30:16 2019
./info  /       Mar 18 00:35:20 2020    Mar 18 00:35:20 2020
./info/packs    *       Mar 18 00:35:20 2020    Mar 18 00:35:20 2020
./pack  /       Mar 18 00:35:19 2020    Mar 18 00:35:19 2020
./pack/pack-d8d97cb38e4c80f3148e06981fc66e4ca3c659ea.idx        *       Mar 18 00:35:19 2020    Mar 18 00:35:19 2020
./pack/pack-d8d97cb38e4c80f3148e06981fc66e4ca3c659ea.pack       *       Mar 18 00:35:19 2020    Mar 18 00:35:15 2020
... #omitted
```

I assume these directories are left over from an interrupted (<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>?) push or something.

The March 2020 run of `git gc` completed successfully, but I still see these `incoming-*` directories going back as far as July 2019. (None of these repos have changed any of the `gc*Expire` settings.)

A manual run of `git gc --prune=now --aggressive` in one of the repos didn't clean these directories up either.

Nothing interesting in the output of `git fsck`:

```
user@host[.../repos/some-repo.git]% git fsck  --unreachable --dangling
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (23585/23585), done.
```

I've only seen one of these directories at a time per repo. Not sure if that's relevant of just happenstance.

Should it matter, I'm running Git version 2.17.0 on the server currently. I'm not sure the historical versions. The server is running FreeBSD 11.2.

The clients are mostly Windows client. They're relatively up-to-date on Git versions as well. The machine I'm writing this on is running version 2.25.1.windows.1.

Comment: The `incoming-*` directories are "quarantine" areas, where Git stuffs objects and/or pack files that have been received from another Git, but are not yet considered part of the repository proper. If a pre-receive or update hook, or Git in general, rejects the push, Git is supposed to remove the quarantine area. If the push is OK, Git migrates the objects from the quarantine area to the repository proper, then deletes the quarantine directory. Either way none of these should remain from anything long ago.

Comment: If you see them in nightly runs or something along those lines, that could be perfectly normal: there might be a `git push` going on at the time.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the quatantine area, @torek. "Either way none of these should remain from anything long ago." And, yet, there are. :-) I don't think these are in-progress pushes since the files/directories I see sitting around are all old. The machine's rebooted since then, so there aren't weird zombie SSH connections. :-) (I've updated the file listing in the question to include the creation & modification times.)

Comment: OK, that sounds like stale, left-over quarantine areas, presumably as a result of an unexpected death of the Git server (before it was able to clean up after itself). Curiously, `git gc` does not remove these; probably it should, with the same rules as for unused objects.